# What's wrong with my R function of logistic map

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, plot

I'm currently learning R at school and I'm stuck with this question:

[image]

This is my code:

```
logistic.map <- function(N0, r, K, tmax) {
  length(N) <- tmax
  N[1] <- N0
  for (i in 1:tmax) N[i+1] <- N[i] + r * N[i] * (1 - N[i] / K)
  return(list(t = 0:tmax, N = tmax))
  }

r1 <- logistic.map(2,0.2,100,50)
r2 <- logistic.map(2,2.2,100,50)
r3 <- logistic.map(2,2.9,100,50)

xlab="Years"
ylab="Population"
plot(r1$t, r1$N, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
plot(r2$t, r2$N, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
plot(r3$t, r3$N, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
```

Whenever I run it it gives back the error:

```
Error in logistic.map(2, 0.2, 100, 50) : object 'N' not found
Error in logistic.map(2, 2.2, 100, 50) : object 'N' not found
Error in logistic.map(2, 2.9, 100, 50) : object 'N' not found
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Also, your function computes values for `N` in a `for` loop and then **does not return them**. It should be `return(list(t = 0:tmax, N = N))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of initializing the output vector in your function is incorrect. Use `N <- numeric(tmax + 1)` instead of `length(N) <- tmax`. Vectors in R uses 1-based indexing not 0-based indexing.

Regarding the returned values, use `return(list(t = 0:tmax, N = N))`.